# How to create an Oracle Database Link when the password has special characters

Tags: oracle-11g, oracle-sql-developer, dblink

I'm trying to create a DBLink. SQL Developer is the client I'm using. The password to my remote user has *'s in it. I'm having trouble figuring this out. This syntax isn't working:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK my_link
CONNECT TO daniel identified by *password
USING 'hostname:port/servicename';
```

I tried '\' and wrapping the password in {}'s,', to no avail. I get a "Command Not Properly Ended" error. Any advice would help. I know it's a simple issue but having trouble figuring it out from googling.

Answer (score 8):

Use quotation marks:

```
CREATE DATABASE LINK my_link
CONNECT TO daniel identified by "*password"
USING 'hostname:port/servicename';
```